# Xcode 7.1 crashes always when debugging is executed

Tags: iphone, debugging, crash, xcode7

If I set a breakpoint and start the debugging mode, Xcode tried to read the attributes and after that Xcode crashes. The position of the breakpoints in the source code has no influence. I tried following steps:
After XCode crashes:

1. If simulator is still running make sure to select IOS Simulator->Reset Content And Settings before closing it.
2. Close Simulator (CMD-Q)
3. Window --> Organizer --> Delete derived data
4. If debugging on ANY devices, delete the app from the device and REBOOT the device completely.
5. Launch XCode
6. Remove All breakpoints
7. Product --> (hold down Alt/option key) Clean Build Folder
8. Product --> Clean
9. Close XCode again via XCode->Quit XCode (NOTE: Must be a GRACEFUL Exit, so XCode can properly do a complete shutdown/cleanup cycle)
10. Reboot your Mac
11. Launch Xcode
12. If running in simulator, pick a different device to simulate than when it crashed.
13. Do a test run of your app (with no breakpoints)
14. If all goes well, start adding a breakpoints (All Exceptions is always a good starting point).

But Xcode still crashes and crashes and ...
I used Xcode 7.1 and Yosemite (I cannot update to El Capitan).

Comment: when it crashes, is there a backtrace or some kind of log that shows where the crash happened?  could you copy that into this question?

Comment: @Qeychon, did you find any solution? This still happens with the latest 7.1.1 release. Very frustrating.

Comment: @mahmud It is no longer crashed when I installed XCode 7.2 beta. But i found no solution for the XCode 7.1.1. I also removed the Xcode 7.1.1 so I could not see the log file anymore. I will install the buggy version again of Xcode and upload the log files.

Comment: still happening for me on 7.2 release build

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode Build Settings there is `Enable Clang Module Debugging` disable it.

Hope,It helps you!